# When the user gives a wrong answer, I want an IMAGE to pop up-like a troll

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I'm developing a quiz application. A very simple one! When the user selects the wrong answer, I want a picture to pop up (TROLL/MEME), stay for a few seconds and then disappear.
How do I do this in a jsp page?

Comment: Yes, and what problem are you having in implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript:

HTML

```
<input id="answer" type="text" /><input id="go" type="button" value="answer" />
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#go').addEventListener('click', function(){
var answer = document.querySelector('#answer').value;
var title = "troll mode";
var imagePath = "http://i.imgur.com/kTUYF.jpg"
if(answer === "" || answer !== "right answer"){
    var win=window.open('','win','resizable=yes,scrollbars=no');
    win.document.write('<html><head><title>' + title + '</title></head><body style="overflow:hidden" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" topmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" scroll="no"><img src="' + imagePath + '"/>');
}});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/5RdWW/2/